# Python : Read from file includes \n \t. The catch is my file also has \n \t as part of the text

Tags: python

My source file looks like below which contains \t \n as part of the text. I need to extract this text from a file, but the extraction adds \n \t. How to avoid \t \n at the same time not removing the \t \n as part of the original text.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS xxx.employee3 ( eid int, name String,
salary String, destination String)
COMMENT 'Employee details'
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
STORED AS TEXTFILE;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS yyy.employee4 ( eid int, name String,
salary String, destination String)
COMMENT 'Employee details'
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

```
with open(ddl_file) as file:
     all_queries = file.read()
     print all_queries
     #splitting the source query based on ;
     list_of_queries = all_queries.split(';')
```

**output:**

```
["CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS KRISM22.employee3 ( eid int, name String,\nsalary String, destination String)\nCOMMENT 'Employee details'\nROW FORMAT DELIMITED\nFIELDS TERMINATED BY '\\t'\nLINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'\nSTORED AS TEXTFILE", "\nCREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS KRISM22.employee4 ( eid int, name String,\nsalary String, destination String)\nCOMMENT 'Employee details'\nROW FORMAT DELIMITED\nFIELDS TERMINATED BY '\\t'\nLINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'\nSTORED AS TEXTFILE", '\n']
```

**Output Expected :**

```
["CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS xxx.employee3 ( eid int, name String,
salary String, destination String)
COMMENT 'Employee details'
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
STORED AS TEXTFILE","CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS yyy.employee4 ( eid int, name String,
salary String, destination String)
COMMENT 'Employee details'
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
STORED AS TEXTFILE;"]
```

Comment: try `print(list_of_queries[0])` and `print(list_of_queries[1])`

Comment: This works. Thanks @MegaIng .